# Fallback CSS background image when setting style with javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, image, fallback

In regular CSS I can use this to set a fallback image incase the first image doesn't exist or failed to load:

```
.container {
  background-image: url(pics/img.webp), url(pics/img.png);
}
```

However, when I set the style in javascript (like with React), how would one achieve this?

Thank you for any help :)

Comment: Same way with CSS? How are you setting it with React?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No different than CSS

```js
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('pics/img.webp'), url('http://placekitten.com/200/300')";
```

If you are styling an element in react, basic idea

```
style={{  
  backgroundImage: `${bgImagePath}, ${bgFallbackPath}`,
  backgroundPosition: 'center',
  backgroundSize: 'cover',
  backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat'
}}
```

Comment: Nice! I thought I tried that yesterday, but I must've done something wrong. It worked now! Thank you :)

Comment: This loads both images, not good for optimization